# What does model.train() function do in tensorlayer Seq2seq model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorlayer

I was reading the tensorlayer documentation and in the NLP section there was a code for chatbots which I studied but could not find what `_model.train()` function do in it. It does not start the training process which I thought would be the role of the function

Comment: Please provide the code which you have tried (do not provide a link, but rather provide actual code snippets) - that will make it much easier for people to provide a useful and timely response.

Answer (score 0):

`train()` means the model is under training mode.
It is useful if your model has dropout, BN and etc.

ref https://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/get_start_model.html